# Inheriting StreamWriter with new filename

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, streamwriter

I want to write code that looks like this:

```
Public Class LogFile
    Inherits StreamWriter

    Private LogsDirectory As String = Application.StartupPath & "\" & "logs\"

    Public Sub New(shortName As String)            
        Dim fullFilePath As String = LogsDirectory & shortName & "_" & Format(Now, "HHmmss") & ".log"    
        MyBase.New(fullFilePath)
    End Sub

End Class
```

However I am forced to do this (because the first statement of `Sub New` must be to a base constructor):

```
 Public Class LogFile  
     Inherits StreamWriter       

    Public Sub New(shortName As String)              
        MyBase.New(Application.StartupPath & "\" & "logs\" & shortName & "_" & Format(Now, "HHmmss") & ".log")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Is there a way 'around' this? In this circumstance it is okay, but I would conceivably like to do more processing that wouldn't fit on a single line.

Comment: The LogsDirectory variable must have its value assigned before it is usable.  Looks like it is automagic in code, but that's just syntax sugar, the constructor takes care of that.  But wait, you are writing the constructor.  The egg has to go before the chicken.  Same applies to MyBase.New().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using a Function so long as it is `Shared` (`LogsDirectory` will also have to be `Shared`)

The following compiles:

```
Public Class LogFile
    Inherits StreamWriter

    Public Sub New(shortName As String)
        MyBase.New(InitFunction(shortName))
    End Sub

    Private Shared LogsDirectory As String = Application.StartupPath & "\" & "logs\"

    Private Shared Function InitFunction(shortname As String) As String
        Dim fullFilePath = LogsDirectory & shortname & "_" & Format(Now, "HHmmss") & ".log"
        Return fullFilePath
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Sorry, in simplifying my code to contain the relevant elements only, I missed a critical element of this - I have edited my question.